# Trying to use "\i [filename]" in psql, getting "invalid argument"

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using Windows 10, Postgres 11.  I have a file `C:\Users\myname\some path\query.sql` containing a typical SELECT query:

```
select a.id,m.toagentid,m.maxstart from agent a
left join
mostrecentfromtopair m 
on
a.id=m.fromagentid
```

When I'm in the `psql` terminal, and I try to run this query as follows:

```
\i "C:\Users\myname\some path\query.sql"
```

then I get this error:

```
\i: Invalid argument
```

How should I be running this .SQL file?

Comment: Why don't use `psql -U your_user -d your_db -f filename.sql`? This command must be in the directory the file..

Answer (score 10):

You can use single quotes and slashes:

```
\i 'C:/Users/myname/some path/query.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

\i 'C:\Users\kprav\Downloads\person.sql'

Always use \ double slashes in between

Use it and now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.
I was able to fix it using / instead of \

for eg. if ur resource(.sql file) is located at **C:\Users\abhis\Downloads\person.sql** and u want to run the person.sql file inside ur database, use:

***\i C:/Users/abhis/Downloads/person.sql***

or just use:

***\i /Users/abhis/Downloads/person.sql***

Answer (score 0):

Always use /(forward slash) instead of \(back slash) in the path reference.

if your .sql file located here
`C:\Users\abc\Downloads\def.sql`
replace all the "\" with "/"

```
\i 'C:/Users/abc/Downloads/def.sql'
```

Exa - Output will be look like below

```
UPDATE 100 (action performed followed by no of rows affected)
INSERT 100 
DELETE 100
```