# using PSQL executing sql format file shows permission denied On Windows platform

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

```
postgres-#  \ir  C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\12\\demo-big-en-20170815.sql
```

Message is `C:: Permission denied`

I already set the security to **Everyone**, so there should be no **Permission issue**

platform is windows, already connected to one database by using PSQL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtabn.jpg)

Comment: Try `\ir  "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/demo-big-en-20170815.sql"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Dear friend. I try another way to do it is by create a very simple sql file then do the  test.
now after i add the quotation marks then there is another messge: 

unrecognized win32 error code: 123"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/createdatabasesupertest.sql: Invalid argument

Comment: The `-` in your command prompt means you have an uncompleted SQL command going on. You wrote some SQL (not beginning with a `\`) and didn't end it with a semicolon `;`. Your command prompt should be `postgres=#`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975117/trying-to-use-i-filename-in-psql-getting-invalid-argument
THIS ONE WORKS. 
I SHOULD CHANGED DOUBLE QUOTE TO SINGLE QUOTE!